# Update Firebase Auth in Google One Tap sign on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose, google-signin

I used the code below to trigger the Google One Tap sign-in modal.

```
 private suspend fun signIn(
        context: Context,
        launcher: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>
    ) {
        val oneTapClient = getSignInClient(context)
        val signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
                BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
                    .setServerClientId(R.string.your_web_client_id.toString())
                    // Only show accounts previously used to sign in.
                    //.setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
                    .build()
            )
            // Automatically sign in when exactly one credential is retrieved.
            //.setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
            .build()

        try {
            // Use await() from https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services
            // Instead of listeners that aren't cleaned up automatically
            val result = oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest).await()

            // Now construct the IntentSenderRequest the launcher requires
            val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result.pendingIntent).build()
            launcher.launch(intentSenderRequest)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
            // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
            Log.d("LOG", e.message.toString())
        }
    }
```

The onCLick in the button is exactly this

```
Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.android_dark_rd_su_4x),
                            contentDescription = "Google login",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(60.dp).clickable {scope.launch {
                                    signIn(
                                        context = context,
                                        launcher = launcher
                                    )
                                } }
                                .constrainAs(next) {
                                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom,)
                                    absoluteRight.linkTo(parent.absoluteRight)
                                },
                        )
```

And I placed this at the top of the composable that has the signin page

```
val context = LocalContext.current

        val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
        ) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // The user cancelled the login, was it due to an Exception?
                if (result.data?.action == ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult.ACTION_INTENT_SENDER_REQUEST) {
                    val exception: Serializable? = result.data?.getSerializableExtra(
                        ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult.EXTRA_SEND_INTENT_EXCEPTION)
                    Log.e("LOG", "Couldn't start One Tap UI: ")
                }
                return@rememberLauncherForActivityResult
            }
            val oneTapClient = getSignInClient(context)
            val credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(result.data)
            val idToken = credential.googleIdToken


            if (idToken != null) {
                // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                // with your backend.
                Log.d("LOG", idToken)
                val firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
                auth.signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                            val user = auth.currentUser
                           // updateUI(user)
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                            //updateUI(null)
                        }
                    }
            } else {
                Log.d("LOG", "Null Token")
            }


        }
```

But, it doesn't update firebase.auth with the current user, even after signin in.

I confirm this by logging the information about the user to the console by using the following code.

```
 auth = Firebase.auth
        Log.d("LOG", auth.currentUser?.displayName.toString() + " " + auth.currentUser?.email.toString())
```

Each time, it returns  `null null` even after a successful sign-in.

**How can I get the login details to populate the firebase.auth credentials, so as to return logged-in user details.**

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you checking that? Can you please edit your question and add the log statement in the actual code?